# How to display multi level headers in Aspose cells Java in MS Excel?

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

Please let me know if Aspose Cells Java API provides a way for doing this?

Please see the attached pic as below : [enter link description here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=multi-level%20header%20gridview&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS525US525&source=lnms&tbm=isch&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=-PvLDiKVudipuM:)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells for Java can do it but it cannot do it automatically. You will have to write a code for it. Please see this image.

[image]

Here the first header has merged cells, Aspose.Cells can merge cells but to merge them, you will have to write the code by yourself.

But if you remove the first header then second header which consists of single cells and its data, which also consists of single cells can be imported to worksheet automatically without writing any code by user via **Cells.importData()** method.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose